# How to merge changed child branch to unchanged parent?

Tags: git

parent_branch (not changed,revision 59ca1f7)

|

-----------------------child_branch (changed, commited, revision 09b3fa3)

I saw a lot of similar questions, they all a little confused and messed with remote branches / changed parent etc / hard reset

My question is very simple:

1. I had a parent_branch
2. git checkout -b child_branch
3. Make changes at child_branch
4. realized that I need to merge the branches
5. What to do? When I checkout to parent_branch and try to merge child_branch Git says:  "parent_branch is already up to date". (although they have difference, I changed child branch)

What is the best practice for it? Rebase?

I've read really many topics on it, there are many solutions like hard reset etc. My case is pure experiment, what is the best to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
git checkout parent_branch
git merge child_branch
```

if it doesn't work, can you augment your question with the output of

```
git log --pretty=oneline --all --decorate --graph
```

so people can analyse your situation better?